# Difference between Dell graphics cards and cards from other vendors?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, dell-inspiron

I've been looking to upgrade my Inspiron 660 with a dedicated graphics card, but I wasn't sure about which cards would work with the budget PSU that came with the computer. Luckily, Dell provides compatibility information with the cards it sells, and the Radeon 7750 is compatible. However, I've done enough research to realize that the charged price (nearly $200 with tax) is more expensive that what that type of card is usually sold for. If I buy this card from somewhere else, like Amazon for example, will it still work, or is there some difference that will interfere?

[The card in question](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=a6523076)

Comment: Yes, most any video card that fits the pciex16 slot (height also) you have will work, only part that can hold things up is your PSU, if it has enough amps on the 12v rail or not, and if it has the extra power connectors if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that is special about the specific graphics card in your question is, that it is a "low profile" card, which means it takes up less space (height wise) in your PC case.

See this picture (although it's not a graphics card it illustrates the difference).

[image]

That would also explain the higher pricetag, as low profile cards are more rarely used than full height cards, they are usually also somewhat more expensive.

Another concern, as you mention, is the PSU power output capacity. So you'd want to look into that as well.

Last but not least, you would want to check that your PSU has a PCIe power plug (if the card you decide to go for needs one):

[image: PCI-E power connector]

You can read more about Low Profile PCIe cards on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI#Low-profile_cards).

Comment: I believe the 7750 is one of the rare cards that doesn't need a PCIe plug, as it is designed for my situation, i.e. upgrading a prebuilt. Disregarding the PCIe, should it work?

Comment: I cant think of any reason why it shouldnt work (except the low profile bracket). As stated in my answer the card needs to be able to fit inside your case.